# Yii CDbCommand queryAll crashes when trying to retrieve big data sets

Tags: php, apache, yii

I am using Yii 1.1.14 and I am trying to retrieve a big data set (~80,000 records / 10 columns) from an oracle 11.2 database.

My problem is that the entire script just crashes after a few minutes without triggering any errors / exceptions.
I also checked the php and apache logs but there is no indication for any error.

The script is executed from a browser and I only get a blank page back with no data.

Here is the code:

```
set_time_limit(0);
$connection = new CDbConnection($dsn,$username,$password);
$command = $connection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM TEST_DATA');
$result = $command->queryAll(); //this is where the script crashes
print_r($result);
//Please disregard any typos, I pasted only a portion of the code.
```

After some debugging, I realize that the script fails on the $command->queryAll() line,
But When I set a limit to 60,000 records (~9MB file) the script dos not fail and I get the results printed on the page, so I know the codes works fine.

I suspect that the crash is related to memory consumption but usually it triggers an error and I have tried raising the memory_limit in php.ini to 256MB but this didn't solve it.
I also tried setting error reporting to E_ALL in order to try and get any errors / exceptions raised.

I am using apache with php 5.3 on a centos 6 server.

I am all out of ideas and I would really appreciate it if anyone here could help me out.

EDIT:
I found the problem, it is a memory issue, I figured out that for a ~10MB result set / 10MB file you will need to set the memory limit on php.ini to 256MB (which is a lot!), I guess I will not use Yii AR but issue a plain php command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can hardly imagine a situation, when 60K records must be printed on the page. I suggest you not doing `findAll()` but using paginated results as in `CGridView` or `CListView`:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider( TestData::model() );

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
));
```

Its very simple to rewrite your code. E.g. if you are doing (even with scopes)

```
TestData::model()->published()->top(5)->findAll()
```

just cut-off last part and you have an argument to `CActiveDataProvider` contructor

```
new CActiveDataProvider( TestData::model()->published()->top(5) );
```

**UPDATE**

Try to query by portions:

```
$limit = 1000 ;
$passes = ceil( Yii::app()->db->createCommand( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {{test_data}}' )->queryScalar() / $limit ) ;

for ( $pass = 0 ; $pass < $passes ; $pass++ ) {
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('*')
        ->from( '{{test_data}}' )
        ->limit( $limit )
        ->offset( $pass * $limit ) ;
    $result = $command->queryAll() ; // here is your peace of data
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I actually need to print it out to the screen because it is being downloaded as csv, I used the print_r command to simplify things in the example above, but I really use fputcsv($handle,$row) where $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w'), it crashes either way though... The problem is that the script doesn't even get to the printing part, it fails at queryAll qithout any error message. any thoughts?

Comment: it works! I guess that this is the best solution so far, but this is a workaround and not addressing the problem directly.. I assume that php is definitely able to handle very large result sets (60k+).this workaround executes multiple queries for a single result and this will have an impact on performance. I wonder if we can solve this by modifying server configurations(php/apache).
I will wait and see if anyone has encountered the same issue before, if nothing will come up I will mark your answer as the solution since this does solve my problem. Thanks again, I really appreciate your help!